# javascript ignore-if-null operator?

Tags: javascript, operator-overloading, null-conditional-operator

In javascript I have a lot of code like this.

```
if (ctrl && ctrl.main && ctrl.main.user) {
    SetTheme(ctrl.main.user.theme);
}
```

which is annoyingly long.  In other, languages you can do simply

```
SetTheme(ctrl?.main?.user?.theme);
```

Is there any way to do that in javascript?

I tried,

```
function safeGet(a,b) { return a ? a[b] : null; }
```

and

```
SetTheme(safeGet(safeGet(safeGet(ctrl, 'main'), 'user'), 'theme'));
```

But that's not very readable.

Comment: The logical AND operator `&&` is your best bet in JavaScript. Anyway, this seems more like a rant about JS to me than a question.

Comment: yeah, sorry. reworded to be less rantish

Comment: @Timo He was asking for a solution - Not only ranting

Comment: *"Is there any way to do that in javascript?"* No. [There have been discussions about this](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/existential-operator-null-propagation-operator), but they haven't led anywhere yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct short cut could be

```
if (((ctrl || {}).main || {}).user) { // ...
```

Or you could use an array as path, or a dot separated string as path and check aginst existence and return the value.

```js
function getValue(object, path) {
    return path.split('.').reduce(function (o, k) {
        return (o || {})[k];
    }, object);
}

var ctrl = { main: { user: { theme: 42 } } };

console.log(getValue(ctrl, "main.user.theme"));
```

Comment: very nice. i like the use of the `||`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a generic function to do this by passing it the string representing the path to the nested property you want:

```
  function getValue(object, prop, /*optional*/ valIfUndefined) {
            var propsArray = prop.split(".");
            while(propsArray.length > 0) {
                var currentProp = propsArray.shift();
                if (object.hasOwnProperty(currentProp)) {
                    object = object[currentProp];
                } else {
                    if (valIfUndefined) {
                        return valIfUndefined;
                    } else {
                        return undefined;
                    }
                }
            }

            return object;
        }
```

Then use this on any object like:

```
// This will return null if any object in the path doesn't exist
if (getValue(ctrl, 'main.user', null)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: OP mentions lack of readability

Comment: I would assume that the lack of readability is in reference to the nested "saveGet" calls. This solution doesn't suffer from that issue.

Comment: True, I guess you can't be too picky with working with JS